# How to coerce a 'pairlist' object to type 'double' (for ggscatter cor.coef)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am using ggscatter to plot a correlation between two variables (alpha, beta). I want to add the correlation coefficients by using the functions cor.coef and cor.method:

```
example <- ggscatter(example, x="beta", y="alpha", 
      add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE,
     cor.coef = TRUE,cor.method = "pearson",
      xlab = "beta", ylab = "alpha", main = "example")
```

The example dataset is a dataframe of 10 numerical variables. Alpha and beta values range between 0 and 1.

I get the following warning message: *"Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type quosure/formula. Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type quosure/formula. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in validDetails.text(x) :   'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"*

Apparently there is a mistake in the dataset. Does someone know how to correct this or another way of adding the correlation coefficients to the ggscatter-plot? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the following script works :

```
library(ggpubr)

alpha <- runif(10, 0, 1)
beta <- runif(10, 0, 1)

example <- data.frame(alpha, beta)

ggscatter(example, x="beta", y="alpha", 
      add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE,
      cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
      xlab = "beta", ylab = "alpha", main = "example")
```

Could you give more details about your data ?

Comment: Okay. For me, this still doesn´t work, allthough the example dataset resembles the data I have. I got a new error though, saying that the packages ggpubr and bindrcpp have been build under the R version 3.4.4. Probably I have to update my R verison.

Comment: Do you know your R version ? You can get it with the command `version`. For me it is 3.4.3. Before updating R, try to update your package maybe.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated my R version and the problem is solved.

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you.